# how to import Maya exported .FBX files into Babylon JS

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, maya, 3dsmax, babylonjs

Does Babylon.js support importing .fbx files like Three.js? if yes how can we do that? I found few options online converting .fbx files to .babylon. Similarly using Unity / 3DS Max to load .fbx and export .babylon from there. That like working with at least two softwares to export it to .babylon from Maya.

Help me understand the best way to export from Maya to Babylon.JS to carry texture, animations too

Comment: I can share some bits I know: Modern browsers are dropping support of everything that's NOT textbased (flash, unity web player, shockwave, etc). FBX 7.0 file is binary format but some programs can export it in json-like text (I think blender does, not sure). FBX 6.4 had an option of choosing export format between binary and text formats. Either way you have to export it in text if you need it in babylon. I don't know about maya but there was a free plugin for Blender to export models straight out to babylon js: [this one](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/Exporters/Blender)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the is no way to export from Maya to BabylonJS. The only ways available are the ones you said:
https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/Exporters

http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/12643-maya-exporter/

> Hi!
>
> We have no plan to build a Maya exporter. The best options are today the 3DS >Max exporter which is by far the most advanced then the Blender exporter. Best >option would then be to open your Maya scene in 3DS to export to .Babylon.
>
> We're still thinking on ways to improve the conversion process. Unity will be >our next step but we have other ideas (like working closely with Clara.io for >instance).
>
> David

Good luck!